# Why is the Pandas read SQL method slower?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

When I run the same query over SSMS it takes 1 second. But when I run it with `pandas.read_sql(query, self.conn)` it takes 10 seconds. What could be causing this slowness? Same SQL Server and same client.

```
queryExecStart = time.time()
sqlDataFrame = pandas.read_sql(query, self.conn)
self.logging(level="info", msg=f"Pandas data read duration {round(time.time() - queryExecStart, 3)} sec. Query: {queryName}")
```

Comment: Please show the query, the query plan, and preferably also tables and index definitions. You can share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: What does `select @@options` output in SSMS and Pandas? Likely they're using different plans due to different client connection options. Can you get the plans out of the cached plan store to compare them?

Comment: Hi, the execution plan is as in the url ->  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkWsH8EEt

Comment: This url is the query plan in the cached plan of the query run on the python client side -> https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1gLuLNEF

Comment: I've collected some new durations. The execution time takes 0.5s (cursor.execute(query)). But it takes more than 5 seconds to get the data with the cursor.fetchall() method. However, SSMS also receives the same size data from the server to the client side. Total time in SSMS ~1 sec. Why does pyodbc take longer to fetch the same size of data to the client side than SSMS?